# How to set title property for span tag dynamically

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I am not able to set the title property for span tag...
I am using the following code

```
 $('.className').find("span").attr("title",'Some_text');
```

Its not working...

Comment: Show us html, it seems alright.

Comment: what's not working?  it works fine here http://jsfiddle.net/Yweed/

Comment: The asp.net tag doesn't seem relevant here.

Comment: this code is ok, you have to debug to see whether **find("span")** is actually returning anything

Comment: as others are saying, the only thing that shouldn't be working is that your jQuery selector isn't returning anything.  Its either not finding `.className`, or its not finding the `span` element inside of the `.className` element.

Comment: Why don't you post your `html` here ?

Comment: how do you do it without Jquery??

Answer (score 29):

Maybe the problem is that you are searching for a span element in a class, this will work for you.

```
$('span.className').attr('title','New Title');​
```

Here you apply the title to all the span elements with that class.

Hope it helps you.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eddiarnoldo/yEyBd/)